# jqGrid on column header click event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jquery and jqGrid and I am looking for an oncolumnheader (or something similar) click event. I have used the "onSortCol:" property of grid but it is not giving me the DOM object on which the click is done. Is there a function or any way to hook click event to a column header in jqGrid?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column headers are `th` elements so it will probably be as easy as:

```
$("#id-of-your-grid th").click(function() {...});
```

Comment: I have a number of grids on a single page with different id's. I was looking for a more generic function.

Comment: In that case, just use the class of the jQgrid: `$(".ui-jqgrid")`

Comment: I have tried that already. It is not working. Instead Sort function of the jqGrid works and my click event is not working

Comment: That could be an issue of timing. If you initialize your click event before jQgrid is initialized, it will not work. Have you tried setting a `setTimeout` of 200?

Comment: Yes it was a timing issue. I was binding event on $(document).ready() whereas my grid was being created later. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try applying your click event after the grid has been created using the gridComplete event.
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
    $("#id-of-your-grid th").click(function() {...});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some body that could not achieve above answers can try below code:

```
 $(".ui-th-column").click((e) => {
            // get the data info of the "e" object from there.
  });
```