# JQgrid: Is there any event that fires when clicked on JQgrid Header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my .net application i am using Jqgrid for generating report.For some reports i need to show  more than one grid , ie; at a time only one grid should be expand .

For doing this i need to know if any Grid header click event is available.

I have checked this event and i can see only "onHeaderClick" event available . onHeaderClick event will fire only we click on expand or cplapse icon on top right corner of each grid Header.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could *probably* attach a delegated event with `on` if there is no standard support.

Comment: thank for the response.Can you just make it little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually bind `click` event handle to the header:

```js
var $grid = $("#grid"); // your grid

$($grid[0].grid.cDiv).click(function() {
    // $mygrid will be the same as $grid, but we can use the expression below
    // to be able to use one even handle for multiple grids
    var $mygrid = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
                      .find(">.ui-jqgrid-bdiv>div>.ui-jqgrid-btable"),
        gridstate = $mygrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "gridstate");
    alert("the header is clicked!\n" +
          "gridstate is now \"" + gridstate + "\"");
});

$grid.bind("jqGridHeaderClick", function (e, gridstate) {
    alert("the icon in the header is clicked!\n" +
          "gridstate is now \"" + gridstate + "\"");
});
```

If required you can simulate the "click" on the icon in the header like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeGridStateOnCaptionClick.htm) do.

Comment: Thanks, it will be very helpful in my proj.

Comment: @Cyber: Like any other event: you should construct jQuery wrapper object which represent all DOM elements and then just use `bind` or `click`. For example, `$(".ui-jqgrid-btable").bind("jqGridHeaderClick", ...);`

Comment: I have a problem in this event.Initially i have three grids, if i click on any grid header all child grids will be Unloaded.In this case if i click on a first grid header all child grid is Unloading ,but if i create all three grids again and tried to click on second grid header ,it is not working. That means after Unloading grid this evens are not working.Any suggestions.

Comment: @Cyber: What you mean under "Unloading"? If you *recreate* the grids you have to rebind the events after every creating of the base `<table>` element.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Grid Unloading means , $('#mygrid').jqGrid('GridUnload'); .How to rebind the event after recreating grid.

Comment: @Cyber: After executing `$('#mygrid').jqGrid('GridUnload')` the whole grid (inclusive all bindings) will be destroied. On the same place will be created empty `<table id="mygrid"></table>`. So you should create *new* grid and then execute one more time the code which I posted (`$($grid[0].grid.cDiv).click` and `$grid.bind("jqGridHeaderClick", ...`). It's what I mean in my previous comment under recreating the grids and rebinding.

Comment: I executed code after recreating grid.Its working .Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
 $(".ui-th-column").click(() => {
            // To do
  });
```

[jqGrid on column header click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483610/jqgrid-on-column-header-click-event/49662820#49662820)